# Метод сортировки подсчетом для вектора

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector

Вот мне нужно в функции, принимающей вектор целочисленных значений, выполнить метод сортировки подсчета!
Смысл сортировки понял, а реализацию на языке не очень.
Нашел в сети код и переделал по вектора:

```
    void couting_max(vector<int>& array)
{
    int max = INT_MIN, min = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > max)
            max = array[i];
        if (array[i] < min)
            min = array[i];
    }
    vector<int>vec;
    int size_ = max + 1 - min;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        int size_ = array[i] - min;
        vec[size_] = vec[size_] + 1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = min; j < max + 1; j++)
    {
        while (vec.at(j - min) != 0)
        {
            array.at(i) = j;
            vec.at(j - min)--;
            i++;
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << "Сортировка выполнена успешно!" << endl;
    output(array);
    system("pause");
}
```

Вроде бы уже всё норм,вроде запустилось, всё норм работает, через отладчик отследил, но реализацию тут не совсем понял! Это функция сортировки по возрастанию, а вот мне еще нужна функция сортировки по убыванию.
Вроде бы просто сделать аналогичную, но всеравно не получается! Куча всего перепробовал, всегда выскакиваю за пределы вектора. Мне не понятно зачем такие огромные массивы создавать и как максимальный элемент становится размерностью вектора, как это работает?
Если кратко, то задача написать такую же функцию, но уже сортировкой по убыванию и пару обьяснений как оно работает.Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да все просто

```
void couting_sort(vector<int>& array)
{
    if (array.size() == 0) return;
    auto p = minmax_element(array.begin(),array.end());
    int min = *p.first;
    int dist = *p.second - min + 1;
    vector<int> t(dist,0);

    for(auto i: array) t[i-min]++;

    for(int i = 0, idx = 0; i < t.size(); ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < t[i]; ++j)
            array[idx++] = i+min;

};
```

Мы просто считаем, сколько элементов каждого вида имеется, запихивая во вспомогательный массив их количество, а потом записываем в отсортированный массив нужное количество элементов, соответствующих индексу вспомогательного массива.

Для сортировки от большего к меньшему надо просто идти по массиву в обратную сторону:

```
for(int i = t.size()-1, idx = 0; i >= 0; --i)
    for(int j = 0; j < t[i]; ++j)
        array[idx++] = i+min;
```

Создавать огромные массивы... ну так такая сортировка и не годится для очень разбросанных элементов. Понятно, что в общем случае требуется 16 гигабайт памяти :), эта сортировка хороша, когда диапазон разброса невелик...

Вот тут https://ideone.com/pxvnqR полная программа.

Comment: я только реализовал тот, который в теме написал метод и тут вы это скинули, вот прям то, что нужно, спасибо, четко работает